# Connect HBase to Grafana

Tags: hbase, grafana

How can HBase be configured as a datasource in Grafana? Is it possible through http api? How to integrate Apache HBase or Spark with Grafana as a reliable datasource?

Comment: What about use ```OpenTSDB``` instead ? you can use HBase as the backend of ```OpenTSDB```. I'm not so sure about if it is ok to develop a plugin to use Hbase directly as a datasource in ```grafana```. If it is, you can start by looking at the content of ```public/app/plugins/datasource```.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you set Ambari as your monitoring system for [Hbase](https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.2/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-chap3-7-5.html) and hadoop services and connect that as [datasoure to your Grafana](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/2558/how-to-use-grafana-to-visualize-metrics-exposed-by.html) it's possible to monitor what ever you want.

Comment: I have similar case and we store business related timeseries data which we would like to visualize, depending on standard set of hadoop services metrics is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going with Apache Phoenix which can provide SQL like access to HBase tables. And then Data Source for Grafana could be more or less cloned from Mysql/postgres data sources.

Anyway I asked here for direct support:
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/16885